# JSP: Why are there so many errors in this session structure?

Tags: jsp

I started with JSP training recently and try to rebuild a simple session from online source.

**index.html**

```
<html>  
 <body>  
  <form action="welcome.jsp">  
   <input type="text" name="uname">  
   <input type="submit" value="go"><br/>  
  </form>  
 </body>  
</html>`
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<html>  
 <body>  
  <%   

   String name=request.getParameter("uname");  
   out.print("Welcome "+name);  

   session.setAttribute("user",name);  

   <a href="second.jsp">second jsp page</a>  

  %>  
 </body>  
</html>
```

**second.jsp**

```
<html>  
 <body>  
  <%   

  String name=(String)session.getAttribute("user");  
  out.print("Hello "+name);  

  %>  
 </body>  [enter image description here][1]
</html>
```

**Image with error messages**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVNmH.jpg]

I do not understand why there are so many errors, as I am following to tutorial strictly.

Comment: May not be related, but you should stay away from using scriptlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you have included your `a` link inside the scriptlet :

```
<html>  
 <body>  
  <%   
   String name=request.getParameter("uname");  
   out.print("Welcome "+name);  
   session.setAttribute("user",name);  
   <a href="second.jsp">second jsp page</a>  //THIS SHOULD BE OUTSIDE SCRIPTLET CODE
  %>  
   <a href="second.jsp">second jsp page</a>  //PUT IT HERE
 </body>  
</html>
```

And you should not be using scriptlets [Read this for more info.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/659757/Wiki/Scriptlets)